# Where have timer be in Viper architecture

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

Let's suppose that every 10 seconds we have to update our data.
Where should we create/store timer and where will it fire associated method in VIPER architecture?
Should ViewController do that and inform presenter? or Presenter should hold the timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating data is not something that a `Presenter` or a `Controller` should be concerned with. `Presenter` (as the name suggests) should only be in control of presentation and stuff. in VIPER architecture, `Interactor` is responsible for handling logics, and "Updating every 10 seconds" sounds like a logic to me. so the Timer should be `Interactor` and upon fire, should inform `Presenter`, then `Presenter` inform `Controller` accordingly. (If you think that's too much boiler-plate, well that's just VIPER)

Answer (score 1):

You can create and store the timer in the Interactor class.

Michal Wojtysiak @ swifting.io wrote a good article about it here:  https://swifting.io/blog/2016/03/13/9-how-to-invalidate-nstimer-properly/?utm_source=swifting.io&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=blog%20post

Answer (score 0):

Interactor class will take care of timer in VIPER architecture.